# Android Crashes After Updating LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I’m trying to update to the latest LibGDX version 1.9.2 (I’ve been using an old version for quite a while) but after creating a new LibGDX project and running the default badlogic logo application it crashes on Android. I’ve created new LibGDX projects plenty of times with no problems, so something must be different now because it’s not working this time. There are no errors in my project and the desktop project works fine, it just simply crashes when I try to run the Android project.

I created a new LibGDX project using the setup application and then went through the Eclipse setup process that I normally go through which has always worked before:

- Setup desktop run configuration to point the assets folder to the Android assets folder
- Configure Android build path, I’ve tried using both Android 4.4 (API 20) and Android 6.0 (API 23)
- Setup Android run configuration to use my Android project and launch on active devices

I've also tried using the SDK Manager to update the Android SDK’s I have installed, re-downloading the LibGDX setup just in case it had gotten corrupted somehow, and deleting/re-creating the project several times but it still doesn’t work.

I’ve also tried googling the error message but most of what I found seems unrelated to LibGDX. Some of the fixes I found were settings issues that are already set correctly in my project. So I’m kind of at a loss here and not sure what the problem is.

Here is the error message:

```
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): Process: com.tekker.metronome, PID: 1641
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tekker.metronome/com.tekker.metronome.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tekker.metronome.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tekker.metronome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tekker.metronome-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tekker.metronome.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tekker.metronome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tekker.metronome-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2978)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     ... 10 more
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tekker.metronome.AndroidLauncher
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         ... 14 more
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tekker.metronome.AndroidLauncher
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):         ... 13 more
04-26 00:59:31.724: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up biting the bullet and installing Android Studio and the new version of LibGDX works fine with that. So I guess it's time to retire the outdated Eclipse + ADT plugin.

Comment: Try eclipse kepler. I know Eclipse Luna has issues with the build.gradle in a libgdx project.

Comment: Are there any benefits to sticking with Eclipse since the ADT plugin is no longer being updated? I've only been putting off moving to Android Studio because I've been more focused on developing than learning a new IDE. But I was able to get LibGDX setup and working semi-quickly so it's not as different as I thought it might be. The one serious issue I've encountered so far is that the builds are extremely slow. It takes between 2 - 5 minutes to build and load the app on my phone. That's certainly not going to work! But it seems to be Gradle related according to the status bar during the build.

Comment: I use Eclipse because it builds and runs the project faster on desktop which is where I test my games. I never really paid much attention to any difference in mobile build times. Building and running on Eclipse takes 2-3 seconds whereas in IntelliJ (and I'm assuming Android Studio) takes a good 15-20 seconds in my experience. Doesn't sound like a big deal but it is when you do it over 100 times a day. Especially in games where tinkering with values happens a lot. Plus for some things you can use the debug mode and change things while the program is running.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was worried about. I do a lot of tinkering and quick loads and long build times would bring that process to a crawl. Even the desktop build took quite a bit longer, but the Android build was insanely long. I'll have to do some research on it and see if there's a way to speed up the build process. I can't imagine many people would be happy about that if the builds are always so slow.

Comment: I have seen your error before and I believe I fixed it by going back to Eclipse Kepler. Sorry, in my original comment I meant to say Eclipse Mars has issues. I didn't test Luna because I already had Kepler on my machine. I don't think I'm missing out on much by using an older version of Eclipse. I also don't understand how those people are happy with slower build times. My only explanation is they just don't know any better. There is always a lot of hype to use the latest newest things in software but doing so can also lead to newer issues.

Comment: Ok, well after trying all kinds of fixes for trying to get Android Studio to build faster and getting absolutely nowhere, I went back to Eclipse (I'm using Luna) and there's a setting in the configurations to update the project to Gradle, so I tried that and it worked! :) The build is still just as fast in Eclipse as before updating to Gradle. So I think I'm going to stick with Eclipse for testing/developing and then when I'm ready to deploy the app I'll use Android Studio just because it is the "official" software supported by Android. That should provide the best of both worlds. :)

Comment: But were you using Luna before when you got the error? I don't think there's any need to use Android Studio just to deploy the app. Once you have Eclipse set up it will work just as well. Android Studio is only better if you're working heavily with the Android framework or you prefer the hotkeys/UI. It doesn't provide any benefit to a libgdx game which is just drawing stuff on a gl view. I think it'll be a pain to get the project running on Eclipse and Android Studio simultaneously but let me know if you end up figuring that out - that might be nice to know.

Comment: Yes, I was using Luna before with the error. I did actually use the same project on Android Studio that I was working on in Eclipse. I setup Android Studio on a different computer (laptop) to test it out. I copied my code files over to the laptop, put them into the project, and it worked fine. I'm also going to be using Fabric (for Crashlytics, MoPub, etc) which is also no longer supporting Eclipse. So I'm ok with playing it safe using Android Studio to make sure my software has all the latest updates for the final release build. But the slow builds certainly won't work for testing/developing.